# NullPointerException when eclipse workbench is closing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, junit4

I am running some automated test using BOJI (Junit), when the tests run completely and it tries to close the workbench I get the following error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-04-25 14:10:23.021
!MESSAGE Error occurred during status handling
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.<init>(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.StatusHandlerRegistry.getDefault(StatusHandlerRegistry.java:91)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.getStatusHandler(StatusManager.java:145)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:204)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager$StatusManagerLogListener.logging(StatusManager.java:317)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.RuntimeLog.logToListeners(RuntimeLog.java:161)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformLogWriter.logged(PlatformLogWriter.java:103)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.safeLogged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:88)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.logPrivileged(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:217)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogReaderServiceFactory.java:189)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogServiceFactory.log(ExtendedLogServiceFactory.java:65)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.ExtendedLogServiceImpl.log(ExtendedLogServiceImpl.java:87)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.LoggerImpl.log(LoggerImpl.java:54)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.Log.log(Log.java:65)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.Policy.log(Policy.java:159)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.reportSnapshotRequestor(SaveManager.java:657)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.close(Workspace.java:575)
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.stop(ResourcesPlugin.java:434)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:830)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:823)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:946)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1580)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:270)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is exactly the same bug reported here

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460863

They mentioned some fix in this thread but I didn't get it

Anyone experienced the same problem and what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

SaveManager called the method on workspace to close and trace indicates that workspace was not closed gracefully.

May be reason could be in the Tests where they might lock any resource which further called by above thread chain.

There is no code so we can not say more about that.